# como pasar datos de un ArrayList a un jtable desde un botón en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, jtable, jbutton

Ayuda, como pasar los elementos de un ArrayList a una tabla por medio de un botón. El programa muestra el resultado por consola, ahora debo realizar la interfaz gráfica para mostrarla al usuario. He tratado de varias maneras y no lo he conseguido. Dejo a continuación la clase y el método.

```
public static final ControladorRequerimientosReto4 controlador = new ControladorRequerimientosReto4();

public static void requerimiento1() {

    System.out.println("*** Asesor por Ciudad ***");
    try {
        ArrayList<AsesorPorCiudad> rankingAsesorPorCiudad = controlador.consultarAsesorPorCiudad();

        for (AsesorPorCiudad asesorPorCiudad : rankingAsesorPorCiudad) {

            System.out.printf("El asesor con ID %d se llama %s %s y reside en %s %n",
                    asesorPorCiudad.getIdLider(),
                    asesorPorCiudad.getNombre(),
                    asesorPorCiudad.getPrimerApellido(),
                    asesorPorCiudad.getCiudadResidencia()
            );
          

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Ha ocurrido un error!" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

para cargar los elementos de un ArrayList a un Jtable, necesitaras haber creado la clase `AsesorPorCiudad` con sus respectivos get y set; te dejo el código comentado.

```
private void requerimiento1(){
    DefaultTableModel modelo =new DefaultTableModel(); //creamos un modelo de tabla por defecto
    JTable miTabla = new JTable; //creamos una tabla
    String[] columnNames = {"ID", "NOMBRE","APELLIDO","CIUDAD"}; //Nombre de la cabecera de nuestra tabla
    modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);  //asignamos cuantas columnas va tener la tabla      
     
    try{
        ArrayList<AsesorPorCiudad> rankingAsesorPorCiudad = controlador.consultarAsesorPorCiudad();

        //creamos un vector de objeto con una longitud del tamaño de columnas de la tabla
        Object[] fila = new Object[modelo.getColumnCount()];
        /*
        Para obtener cada elemento de nuestro vector rankingAsesorPorCiudad, 
        tenemos que crear la clase AsesorPorCiudad (supongo que ya lo tienes) 
        con sus respectivos set y get para acceder a cada elemento
       */
        for (int i = 0;i<rankingAsesorPorCiudad.size();i++) {
            fila[0] = rankingAsesorPorCiudad.get(i).getId();
            fila[1] = rankingAsesorPorCiudad.get(i).getNombre();
            fila[2] = rankingAsesorPorCiudad.get(i).getApellido();
            fila[3] = rankingAsesorPorCiudad.get(i).getCiudad();            
            modelo.addRow(fila);//agregamos una fila a nuestro modelo de tabla
         }

         miTabla.setModel(modelo); //agregamos nuestro modelo a nuestra tabla

       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
          System.err.println("Ha ocurrido un error!" + e.getMessage());
       }  
}
```

Si tienes alguna duda me escribes, ya que he escrito sin un IDE talvez se me paso algo

Comment: gracias, ya lo estoy probando, pero me podrías explicar la manera de hacer que ese código se ejecute desde el botón que se encuentra fuera de esa clase, créeme que ya he  desarmado el código y vuelto a poner como esta, pero se ya estoy que reviento

Comment: @JulianSoto cada boton tiene un evento ``ActionPerformed`` crea un objeto de la clase donde se encuentra el método ``requerimiento1`` luego llama al método ``requerimiento1``